# Lazy load module error Uncaught (in promise): TypeError

Tags: angular

I'm new to Angular. I'm trying to follow [this](https://angular.io/guide/lazy-loading-ngmodules) guide.
I did exactly the same step by step but I'm getting an error. Am I missing something?

> Error
>   ​
>       columnNumber: 31 
>   ​
>       fileName: "http://localhost:4200/polyfills.bundle.js line 597 > eval"
>   ​
>       lineNumber: 814
>   ​
>   message: "Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: **webpack_require**.e is not a function\nwebpackAsyncContext@webpack-internal:///./src/$$_lazy_route_resource:23:9\nSystemJsNgModuleLoader.prototype.loadAndCompile@webpack-internal:///./node_modules/@angular/core/esm5/core.js:6786:16\nSystemJsNgModuleLoader.prototype.load@webpack-internal:///./node_modules/@angular/core/esm5/core.js:6770:55\nRouterConfigLoader.prototype.loadModuleFactory@webpack-internal:///./node_modules/@angular/router/esm5/router.js:4678:110\nRouterConfigLoader.prototype.load@webpack-internal:///./node_modules/@angular/router/esm5/router.js:4658:47\nApplyRedirects.prototype.getChildConfig/<@webpack-internal:///./node_modules/@angular/router/esm5/router.js:2144:96\nMergeMapSubscriber.prototype._tryNext@webpack-internal:///./node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/operators/mergeMap.js:133:22\nMergeMapSubscriber.prototype._next@webpack-internal:///./node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/operators/mergeMap.js:123:13\nSubscriber.prototype.next@webpack-internal:///./node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/Subscriber.js:100:13\nScalarObservable.prototype._subscribe@webpack-internal:///./node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/observable/ScalarObservable.js:53:13\nObservable.prototype._trySubscribe@webpack-internal:///./node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/Observable.js:177:20\nObservable.prototype.subscribe@webpack-internal:///./node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/Observable.js:165:88\nMergeMapOperator.prototype.call@webpack-internal:///./node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/operators/mergeMap.js:97:16\nObservable.prototype.subscribe@webpack-internal:///./node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/Observable.js:162:13\nMergeMapOperator.prototype.call@webpack-internal:///./node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/operators/mergeMap.js:97:16\nObservable.prototype.subscribe@webpack-internal:///./node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/Observable.js:162:13\nCatchOperator.prototype.call@webpack-internal:///./node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/operators/catchError.js:83:16\nObservable.prototype.subscribe@webpack-internal:///./node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/Observable.js:162:13\nsubscribeToResult@webpack-internal:///./node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/util/subscribeToResult.js:32:20\nMergeMapSubscriber.prototype._innerSub@webpack-internal:///./node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/operators/mergeMap.js:143:18\nMergeMapSubscriber.prototype._tryNext@webpack-internal:///./node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/operators/mergeMap.js:140:9\nMergeMapSubscriber.prototype._next@webpack-internal:///./node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/operators/mergeMap.js:123:13\nSubscriber.prototype.next@webpack-internal:///./node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/Subscriber.js:100:13\nMapSubscriber.prototype._next@webpack-internal:///./node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/operators/map.js:88:9\nSubscriber.prototype.next@webpack-internal:///./node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/Subscriber.js:100:13\nArrayObservable.prototype._subscribe@webpack-internal:///./node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/observable/ArrayObservable.js:121:17\nObservable.prototype._trySubscribe@webpack-internal:///./node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/Observable.js:177:20\nObservable.prototype.subscribe@webpack-internal:///./node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/Observable.js:165:88\nMapOperator.prototype.call@webpack-internal:///./node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/operators/map.js:60:16\nObservable.prototype.subscribe@webpack-internal:///./node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/Observable.js:162:13\nMergeMapOperator.prototype.call@webpack-internal:///./node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/operators/mergeMap.js:97:16\nObservable.prototype.subscribe@webpack-internal:///./node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/Observable.js:162:13\nFirstOperator.prototype.call@webpack-internal:///./node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/operators/first.js:74:16\nObservable.prototype.subscribe@webpack-internal:///./node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/Observable.js:162:13\nCatchOperator.prototype.call@webpack-internal:///./node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/operators/catchError.js:83:16\nObservable.prototype.subscribe@webpack-internal:///./node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/Observable.js:162:13\nMapOperator.prototype.call@webpack-internal:///./node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/operators/map.js:60:16\nObservable.prototype.subscribe@webpack-internal:///./node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/Observable.js:162:13\nsubscribeToResult@webpack-internal:///./node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/util/subscribeToResult.js:32:20\nMergeMapSubscriber.prototype._innerSub@webpack-internal:///./node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/operators/mergeMap.js:143:18\nMergeMapSubscriber.prototype._tryNext@webpack-internal:///./node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/operators/mergeMap.js:140:9\nMergeMapSubscriber.prototype._next@webpack-internal:///./node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/operators/mergeMap.js:123:13\nSubscriber.prototype.next@webpack-internal:///./node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/Subscriber.js:100:13\nScalarObservable.prototype._subscribe@webpack-internal:///./node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/observable/ScalarObservable.js:53:13\nObservable.prototype._trySubscribe@webpack-internal:///./node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/Observable.js:177:20\nObservable.prototype.subscribe@webpack-internal:///./node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/Observable.js:165:88\nMergeMapOperator.prototype.call@webpack-internal:///./node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/operators/mergeMap.js:97:16\nObservable.prototype.subscribe@webpack-internal:///./node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/Observable.js:162:13\nLastOperator.prototype.call@webpack-internal:///./node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/operators/last.js:43:16\nObservable.prototype.subscribe@webpack-internal:///./node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/Observable.js:162:13\nMapOperator.prototype.call@webpack-internal:///./node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/operators/map.js:60:16\nObservable.prototype.subscribe@webpack-internal:///./node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/Observable.js:162:13\nMapOperator.prototype.call@webpack-internal:///./node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/operators/map.js:60:16\nObservable.prototype.subscribe@webpack-internal:///./node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/Observable.js:162:13\nMapOperator.prototype.call@webpack-internal:///./node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/operators/map.js:60:16\nObservable.prototype.subscribe@webpack-internal:///./node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/Observable.js:162:13\nCatchOperator.prototype.call@webpack-internal:///./node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/operators/catchError.js:83:16\nObservable.prototype.subscribe@webpack-internal:///./node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/Observable.js:162:13\nMergeMapOperator.prototype.call@webpack-internal:///./node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/operators/mergeMap.js:97:16\nObservable.prototype.subscribe@webpack-internal:///./node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/Observable.js:162:13\nMergeMapOperator.prototype.call@webpack-internal:///./node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/operators/mergeMap.js:97:16\nObservable.prototype.subscribe@webpack-internal:///./node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/Observable.js:162:13\nMapOperator.prototype.call@webpack-internal:///./node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/operators/map.js:60:16\nObservable.prototype.subscribe@webpack-internal:///./node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/Observable.js:162:13\nMergeMapOperator.prototype.call@webpack-internal:///./node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/operators/mergeMap.js:97:16\nObservable.prototype.subscribe@webpack-internal:///./node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/Observable.js:162:13\nMergeMapOperator.prototype.call@webpack-internal:///./node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/operators/mergeMap.js:97:16\nObservable.prototype.subscribe@webpack-internal:///./node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/Observable.js:162:13\nMergeMapOperator.prototype.call@webpack-internal:///./node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/operators/mergeMap.js:97:16\nObservable.prototype.subscribe@webpack-internal:///./node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/Observable.js:162:13\nMapOperator.prototype.call@webpack-internal:///./node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/operators/map.js:60:16\nObservable.prototype.subscribe@webpack-internal:///./node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/Observable.js:162:13\nObservable.prototype.forEach/<@webpack-internal:///./node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/Observable.js:209:28\nZoneAwarePromise@webpack-internal:///./node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js:891:29\nObservable.prototype.forEach@webpack-internal:///./node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/Observable.js:205:16\nRouter.prototype.activateRoutes@webpack-internal:///./node_modules/@angular/router/esm5/router.js:5626:9\nRouter.prototype.runNavigate/<@webpack-internal:///./node_modules/@angular/router/esm5/router.js:5588:13\nZoneAwarePromise@webpack-internal:///./node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js:891:29\nRouter.prototype.runNavigate@webpack-internal:///./node_modules/@angular/router/esm5/router.js:5519:16\nRouter.prototype.executeScheduledNavigation/<@webpack-internal:///./node_modules/@angular/router/esm5/router.js:5474:24\nZoneDelegate.prototype.invoke@webpack-internal:///./node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js:388:17\nonInvoke@webpack-internal:///./node_modules/@angular/core/esm5/core.js:4976:24\nZoneDelegate.prototype.invoke@webpack-internal:///./node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js:387:17\nZone.prototype.run@webpack-internal:///./node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js:138:24\nscheduleResolveOrReject/<@webpack-internal:///./node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js:872:29\nZoneDelegate.prototype.invokeTask@webpack-internal:///./node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js:421:17\nonInvokeTask@webpack-internal:///./node_modules/@angular/core/esm5/core.js:4967:24\nZoneDelegate.prototype.invokeTask@webpack-internal:///./node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js:420:17\nZone.prototype.runTask@webpack-internal:///./node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js:188:28\ndrainMicroTaskQueue@webpack-internal:///./node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js:595:25\n"

Comment: Provide some code about where you stop.

Answer (score 1):

This usually happen when the lazy module throws an error in the first build.
Create build again will fix your issue!!

Try to run "ng serve" or "ng serve --aot" again

Comment: I tried but does nothing. It compiles and I get the error (error saying actually nothing....) in the console.

Answer (score 0):

Ok I found what causes the error.

I was typing (not copying) code from the guide.

I only added paths to modules and I forgot to add 'default' route in app-routing.module.ts

```
{
  path: '',
  redirectTo: '',
  pathMatch: 'full'
}
```

Routes are working now, and no errors!